# Interaction with printed stats and token/equipment with stat reduction

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I just debuted playing magic 2 weeks ago, and I have a question. Let's say a creature has 4 +1/+1 token on it and has base stats of 2/2. If I play [Breya, Etherium Shaper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBreya%2c%20Etherium%20Shaper%5d)'s ability to inflict -4/-4 to that creature, does it affect the creature with all his power (6/6 bringing it down to 2/2) or does it affect the printed value of 2/2, killing it since it goes to 0 toughness?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "+1/+1 token"; those are called *counters*, not tokens.  Counters are featureless markers placed on things.  A token is a permanent (planeswalker, land, artifact, creature, and/or enchantment) that is represented by something other than a *Magic* card.

Answer (score 8):

It becomes 2/2.

---

The ability in question is

> Target creature gets -4/-4 until end of turn.

To determine a creature's power and toughness:

1. Start with the printed value (or the value with which a token was created).
2. Apply power- and toughness-setting effects (e.g [Turn to Frog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTurn%20to%20Frog%5d)) in the order they were created.
3. Apply power- and toughness-modifying effects (e.g the ability and the counters mentioned above).

The result is the power and toughness of the creature.

Comment: Important to note: State Based Actions (such as "should this creature die") are NOT checked in between these steps, so theoretically a creature could have negative toughness somewhere in the process of calculating it's stats, but as long as it ends up with positive toughness at the end it's okay.

Comment: More precisely, only the final values are the creature's power and toughness. *Nothing* sees the intermediary values. Not SBAs, not triggers, nothing.